# Confusion with c++11?

Tags: c++, c++11

Can anyone explain to me thoroughly what c++11 is? And, I was wondering, how would you upgrade the entire language on windows if its native code *is* c++. I am so confused. Thanks.
P.S. I searched for hours dont vote the question down just for that.

Comment: try http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B11 , it has quite a bit of information.

Comment: I searched and read the whole wikipedia. I still dont understand.

Comment: The _whole_ Wikipedia? O.o

Comment: The whole c++11 thing lol.

Answer (score 2):

C++ programs that have already been compiled are not affected by a C++ update. A C++ language update only affects you if you're a **programmer** who chooses to use a new version of a compiler which supports C++11. It doesn't impact **users** of C++ programs.

Furthermore, it only impacts individual programmers who use a new compiler. It doesn't impact programmers who continue using their old compilers. It also, except in rare cases, won't affect programmers who use a new C++11 compiler but don't use any C++11-specific features.

Comment: How do you "get" c++11?

Comment: @MrJavaCoffee: The same way you "get" C++: you download a compiler that implements the C++ standard.

Comment: VC2012 does not support C++11. It supports *some* of C++11. Slightly more than 2010, but not vastly more. And certainly not *most* of C++11.

Answer (score 1):

c++11 is the new version of c++. Because it is backwards compatible it can still compile old c++ code. Further, adding new language features to compilers does not upgrade existing code.

Answer (score 1):

You may think of as a new version of a software. Like Word 2007 and Word 2010.

- The newer version can still read documents from old version, in some rare cases you need to make some small changes but in general, you can continue to use the old documents.
- When you start using Word 2010 and the new features that it offeres, your new documents can no longer be used with Word 2007.
- No one is forcing you to use Word 2010, you can still use Word 2007 if you like. The people using newer versions can still read your documents.
- You will occasionally be send a document from someone who is using the new version and you can not use it.

All of this applies to C++03 and C++11 in almost the same way:

- A C++03 program can be compiled with a C++11 compiler, only in some rare cases you need to make small changes, but in general it will work.
- If you write a C++11 program using C++11's features, C++03 compilers will not compile your code.
- You don't have to use the new C++11 features
- If someone else's code is using C++11 features and you don't want to use a C++11 compiler (or enable the C++11 mode of your compiler), you can not simply use the new code.

Hope this helps to create a better idea about C++11 for you!